# mysql get records associated directly and indirectly

Tags: mysqli

I have 3 tables let's say

> manager(id, name) 
> teamleader(id, name, associated)
>   employee(id,name,code)

In **teamleader** table associated is foreign key of **manager** table.

In **employee** table code is either id of **manager or teamleader** .

Employee is under manager as well as teamleader.

I want to write a query to find employee which directly under by manager and under teamleader which are associated with that manager.

Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Please explain how "under" is represented in your schema.

Comment: means i want to display employee which are directly associated with that particular manager also indirectly associated with that manager .

Comment: provide query which you have tried

Comment: Select * from `employee ` where `code` = '1003'

Comment: @Danny pls check the query i posted and let me know if its what you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you question correctly you can try this:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.name,
    IF(m1.id IS NULL,m1.id,m2.id) as manager_id
FROM 
    employee e
LEFT JOIN manager m1
    ON m1.id = e.code
LEFT JOIN teamleader t1
    ON t1.id = e.code 
LEFT JOIN manager m2
    ON m2.id = t1.associated
WHERE
    (
        m1.id IS NOT NULL
        OR
        (
            t1.id IS NOT NULL
            AND
            m2.id IS NOT NULL
        )
    )
```

If you want to put a condition on a specific manager just add at the end :
`HAVING manager_id = x`
where x is the manager id that you wanted

Comment: hey thanks a lot... i have made some basic changes and its working